# reading function from another file into a button in python

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

I'm making a main code in Python 3.6 called gui_check.py.

The code looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from urlread import givenumbers

top = Tk()
top.geometry("400x400")

B = Button(top, text = "Hello", command = givenumbers())
B.place(x = 50,y = 50)

top.mainloop()
```

In this code, there is a function called `givenumbers()` which is a function from another file (called urlread.py) that prints numbers.

The result I wanted to get is a gui with a button that when I click on it, it calls the function `givenumber()`.
However, the result I get is that when I run the code it runs `givenumber()` (print the numbers) while opening the gui even without me clicking on the button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses in:

```
B = Button(top, text = "Hello", command = givenumbers())
```

So you should have:

```
B = Button(top, text = "Hello", command = givenumbers)
```

instead.

Read http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm